# encodeRedirectURL generates warning

Tags: java, servlets, urlencode

I am using a static analysis tool that find bugs and reports warning on the following code

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(redirectToXXX));
```

the warning says:

> This code directly writes an HTTP parameter to an HTTP header, which
>   allows for a HTTP response splitting vulnerability.

But when I do it like this:

```
redirectToXXX= java.net.URLEncoder.encode(redirectToXXX.toString(),"ISO-8859-1");
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(redirectToXXX));
```

the warning disappears.

What I don't understand is that `encodeRedirectURL` is supposed to encode the url if necessary, so why does it generates a warning then, and remove the warning when encoded with URLEncoder.encode.

Comment: Where does redirectToXXX come from? Also what tool are you using?

Comment: redirectToXXX contains some parameters from the HttpServletRequest, I am using FindBugs for the analysis.

Comment: The parameters have CRLF in it. Remove them and try.

Comment: Thank you Dandy, removing CRLF works ! I was just wondering if I should just remove CR AND LF (combination) or remove CR OR LF ?
there is no warning with using either for the two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that in the second case, the warning disappear because `URLEncoder.encode` remove CR and LF that could be contained in the parameter you are taking from the request.

You might want to read [this](http://www.securiteam.com/securityreviews/5WP0E2KFGK.html) to understand the background of the HTTP response splitting vulnerability.
I believe also that since the call to `URLEncoder.encode` returns a new object, FindBugs doesn't reconduce that variable to the HTTP Request content, so it considers it safe.

Comment: yeah, removing CR and LF removed the warning, I replaced the CR and LF with redirectToXXX.replaceAll("(\\r\\n)", "") but I am not sure if I should remove just the combinations of CR and LF or remove CR or LF wherever they appear (like this redirectToXXX.replaceAll("(\\r | \\n)", ""); ?

Comment: Well, HTTP specifies that a new line is represented by a CRLF (\r\n). But I believe it wouldn't hurt to remove them all.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `redirectToXXX` contains carriage return or line feed. Please remove that and try again.